# manually plot hist(X, freq = FALSE)

Tags: r, histogram

I plot

```r
set.seed(123)
X <- rnorm(100)
hist(X, freq = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

in R, and I try to manually plot `hist(X, freq = FALSE)` as

```r
breaks <- seq(-2.5, 2.5, by = 0.5)
freq_table <- table(cut(X, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))
freq <- freq_table / sum(freq_table)
barplot(freq, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", names.arg = names(freq_table))
```

Why the ylabs of two plots are different?

Btw, one can plot them together for comparison

```r
set.seed(123)
X <- rnorm(100)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

hist(X, freq = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")

breaks <- seq(-2.5, 2.5, by = 0.5)
freq_table <- table(cut(X, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))
freq <- freq_table / sum(freq_table)
barplot(freq, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", names.arg = names(freq_table))
```

Comment: Notice that, if `freq = FALSE` ist set in `hist()` density is plotted. Hence, you can change to: `(h = hist(X, freq = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n")); barplot(height = h$density, xaxt = "n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate `freq`, you should normalize it by `mean(diff(breaks))`.

The reason behind is that, in `hist`, `density` depends on the interval between breaks (type `?hist` in prompt and read the manual)

[image]

and you have `0.5` as the break length, that means in `barplot` you need to manually amplify the density by `1/0.5=2` to achieve roughly the same scale in y-axis as in `hist`.

## Code (Example)

```
set.seed(123)
X <- rnorm(100)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

hist(X, freq = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")

breaks <- seq(-2.5, 2.5, by = 0.5)
freq_table <- table(cut(X, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))
freq <- freq_table / sum(freq_table) / mean(diff(breaks)) # this is the term that affects the `density`
barplot(freq, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", names.arg = names(freq_table))
```

and you will see that

[image]

Comment: Very impressive for  `mean(diff(breaks))` to  normalization @ThomasIsCoding